# adapt excel formula so that i can fill across and down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

basically im using a countifs formula to count the amount of records in another sheet which meet a certain criteria. The main criteria is time and moves up in increments of 15 mins. There are 96 periods of 15 mins in a day and i also need to fill down. I have the formula to work but if i want to fill across as well as fill down it has stumped me. Here is myspreadsheet

```
10/02/2016  00:00   00:15   00:30   00:45
Market      Trades  Trades  Trades
de30                1
tscol               6
uk100               8
audusd              1
eurgbp              2
```

Basically its counting the amount of trades in that asset in the 15 minute period. so in c3 i have this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$F:$F,Sheet3!A3,Sheet1!$Q:$Q,Sheet3!$A$1,Sheet1!$S:$S,">="&Sheet3!$B$1,Sheet1!$S:$S,"<"&Sheet3!$C$1)
```

Comment: you need to play with the relative or absolute reference to the cell as is defined by `$` in front of the column and row reference for any cell references in the formula. The `$` makes the column / row **absolute** and will not change as you drag the formula. Removing the `$` makes the cell reference relative. I would be more specific, but it's hard to without seeing a sample of both `Sheet1` and `Sheet3`.

Comment: Can you label the rows/columns on your example?  Is this Sheet1 or Sheet3?  What does the other sheet look like?  Scott Holtzman is right, experimenting with the "$" will help you learn how they work - they're the key to answering your question.

Comment: Hello, thank you. sheet 1 contains a 1000 records of different trades, so basically this sheet will count them based on the 15 minute slots. I understand cell referencing, i was just wondering when I fill across and fill down the absolute reference will need to change. Hugely time consuming and was wondering if there is a better way to write out my formula?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do can be solved with proper referencing. When you assign a reference in your formula, you can press F4 to add the `$` to your reference. If you set it before de the letter (the column pointer) the horizontal drag will not change the column. If you set it before the number (the row pointer) the vertical drag will not change the row.

So, for the references to the time, set the reference with the `$` before the number, and for the references to the Market, set the reference with `$` before the letter:

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$F:$F,Sheet3!A3,Sheet1!$Q:$Q,Sheet3!$A$1,Sheet1!$S:$S,">="&Sheet3!B$1,Sheet1!$S:$S,"<"&Sheet3!C$1)`